# On click, swap item with top level item

Tags: jquery, replace, this, swap, dom-traversal

I'm looking to swap the content of an element with the content of another element in the div.

I've created a fiddle but it has a couple problems:

https://jsfiddle.net/2o3u0366/

```
$('.value').click(function(){
var newValue = $(this).text();
$(this).replaceWith( $('.header').text() );
$('.header').text(newValue);
});

<div class="dropdown">
<h2 class="header">This</h2>
<h2 class="value">That</h2>
<h2 class="value">Three</h2>
<h2 class="value">Four
</h2>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
<h2 class="header">This</h2>
<h2 class="value">That</h2>
<h2 class="value">Three</h2>
<h2 class="value">Four</h2>
</div>
```

I'm looking to have it pull from the div that the elements are currently in. As you can see in the example, it's pulling it from each div of the same class. I can't figure out where to put a "THIS" statement or how I can traverse the DOM in order to make this function work.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/axo8d65c/

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use `.closest()` to go up to the containing div, then `.find()` to get the header item within that div. Note also that you don't need `.replaceWith()` because you just want to set the text. In the following code I've created variables that refer to the current item and the header, to save from having repeated calls to `$()` with the same selectors.

```js
$('.value').click(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var $header = $this.closest(".dropdown").find('.header');
  var newValue = $this.text();
  $this.text( $header.text() );
  $header.text(newValue);
});
```

```css
.dropdown { float: left; margin-right: 100px; }
.dropdown:first-of-type { background: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
<h2 class="header">This</h2>
<h2 class="value">That</h2>
<h2 class="value">Three</h2>
<h2 class="value">Four
</h2>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
<h2 class="header">This</h2>
<h2 class="value">That</h2>
<h2 class="value">Three</h2>
<h2 class="value">Four</h2>
</div>
```